# Streaming *to* a HTTP connection with CFNetwork?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfnetwork

I realize this is the exact opposite of what most people want to do, however, for various technical requirements, it's something I'd like to accomplish.

CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest allows one to specify a CFReadStream... but I would like to connect to the server and use a *write* stream directly for the request.

Example:

- connect
- serialize to output stream
- check response code
- deserialize from input instream

This is the pattern that other frameworks on other platforms take.  The only idea I can come up with is using a pipe, but that seems fragile and potentially not even compatible with CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is CFStreamCreateBoundPair() that creates pair of read/write streams that behave like pipe. It is probably the best that CFNetwork offers for your task.